# How to make text replacent between files with awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to use awk in order to make specific substitutions in a text file
based on values taken from another file. More in detail and using simple
examples, I have a raw file A.txt that must be processed:

```
000  y4fy      1  0h0l
000  rft5      1  yrt3
000  g34y      1  ht74
000  ll90      2  t964
000  ew3x      2  472e
000  jo7e      3  6rhf
000  f5gg      4  gs84
000  wp5y      5  6rru
000  3em1      6  c2cn
000  pti1      7  ldr3
000  4vhd      7  epp3
000  2kfb      8  twtv
```

and so on...

A second file B.txt contains a subset of values of $3 field of A.txt:

```
2
5
7
```

I am tryng to make specific replacements in the $4 field of A.txt
based in values of B.txt.

Now, we can distinguish two different cases.

Case_1: the susbstitution text is a single string, let's say `TTTT`, and
the output should be:

```
000  y4fy      1  0h0l
000  rft5      1  yrt3
000  g34y      1  ht74
000  ll90      2  TTTT
000  ew3x      2  TTTT
000  jo7e      3  6rhf
000  f5gg      4  gs84
000  wp5y      5  TTTT
000  3em1      6  c2cn
000  pti1      7  TTTT
000  4vhd      7  TTTT
000  2kfb      8  twtv
```

in which the format is preserved.

Case_2: the susbstitution text is associated to a specific value in
B.txt, such as:

```
2   HHHH
5   AAAA
7   MMMM
```

and the output should be:

```
000  y4fy      1  0h0l
000  rft5      1  yrt3
000  g34y      1  ht74
000  ll90      2  HHHH
000  ew3x      2  HHHH
000  jo7e      3  6rhf
000  f5gg      4  gs84
000  wp5y      5  AAAA
000  3em1      6  c2cn
000  pti1      7  MMMM
000  4vhd      7  MMMM
000  2kfb      8  twtv
```

Basically, looks to me case_1 is a particular instance of case_2.

Because such process involves hundreds of very long files, I am
trying to find a solution that use awk instead of the slower while
read loop in bash.

After a couple of days, the best code I got for the case_1 is:

```
while read val; do awk -v x="$val" '{if ($1 == "0000" && $3 == x) $4 = "TTTT" ; else print $0}' A.txt; done < B.txt > res.txt
```

which does not work, of course.
I wonder if someone could provide a solution for case_1 and,
hopefully, for case_2 as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

**Case 1:**

```sh
cat file1
2
5
7

cat file2
000  y4fy      1  0h0l
000  rft5      1  yrt3
000  g34y      1  ht74
000  ll90      2  t964
000  ew3x      2  472e
000  jo7e      3  6rhf
000  f5gg      4  gs84
000  wp5y      5  6rru
000  3em1      6  c2cn
000  pti1      7  ldr3
000  4vhd      7  epp3
000  2kfb      8  twtv
```

Then use awk as:

```sh
awk 'NR == FNR {map[$1] = $2; next} $3 in map {s = (map[$3] == "" ? "TTTT" : map[$3]); sub(/[^[:blank:]]+$/, s)} 1' file1 file2

000  y4fy  1  HHHH
000  rft5  1  HHHH
000  g34y  1  HHHH
000  ll90  2  TTTT
000  ew3x  2  TTTT
000  jo7e  3  AAAA
000  f5gg  4  gs84
000  wp5y  5  TTTT
000  3em1  6  c2cn
000  pti1  7  TTTT
000  4vhd  7  TTTT
000  2kfb  8  MMMM
```

---

**Case 2:**

```sh
cat file1

2   HHHH
5   AAAA
7   MMMM
```

Then run it as:

```sh
awk 'NR == FNR {map[$1] = $2; next} $3 in map {s = (map[$3] == "" ? "TTTT" : map[$3]); sub(/[^[:blank:]]+$/, s)} 1' file1 file2

000  y4fy  1  0h0l
000  rft5  1  yrt3
000  g34y  1  ht74
000  ll90  2  HHHH
000  ew3x  2  HHHH
000  jo7e  3  6rhf
000  f5gg  4  gs84
000  wp5y  5  AAAA
000  3em1  6  c2cn
000  pti1  7  MMMM
000  4vhd  7  MMMM
000  2kfb  8  twtv
```

To make it more readable:

```sh
awk 'NR == FNR {  # while processing first file
   map[$1] = $2   # store $2 in an associative array with key as $1
   next
}
$3 in map {       # if $3 is found in associative array
   # set $4=TTTT when value is empty otherwise use value stored in array
   s = (map[$3] == "" ? "TTTT" : map[$3])
   sub(/[^[:blank:]]+$/, s)
} 1' file1 fil22
```

Comment: the output file you get is not as expected and I posted. Your input file (file1) is not the same as mine (B.txt). You kind mixed up the two cases.

Comment: I merged both cases into one input file so that same awk command can work for both the cases. Is it not working?

Comment: just compare my expected outputs for the two cases with yours and you would realize It is not working.

Comment: thanks so much for you code, it works fine. Could you please explain the code especially how and why did you use the map function?

Comment: `map` is not a function. It is just name of an array. It can be anything like `arr` also. I have added explanation.

Comment: Anyway, I just noticed that your solution does not maintain the original format of the input file. So, I need to reformat the output.